# javascript, firefox addon, open new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, firefox-addon

I have an addon that open a html page when you click a button on the browser bar (so far so good)
in the html page I have this javascript:

```
    function new_version_show_window()
        {
            if (prefManager.getCharPref("extensions.mf_unblocker.blocker_version_in_prefs") != this_version)
            {


                gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("http://mfre.com/mf/new_install_'+this_version+'.html");    
            }
        }
```

But I am getting the error:

```
gBrowser is undefined
```

The javascript is in

```
chrome://mf_unblocker/content/0_register.html
```

so I am very much still in the browser extension 
how do i get it to open a new tab?

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var win = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1']
                  .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                  .getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
                win.gBrowser.selectedTab = win.gBrowser.addTab(url);
```

Assuming url is the URL to be opened