# Firefox addon SDK, open an url automatically after Firefox startup?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

With Firefox addon SDK, how to open specific url automatically after Firefox startup (for the purpose of testing page)

I've tried `tabs.open(url)` in [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Open_a_Web_Page):

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example.com");
```

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701258/javascript-firefox-addon-open-new-tab) and a lot of Stackoverflow page ..., but none of them works at all...(It is still just a blank tab after `$ cfx run`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do this:

```
const tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

exports.main = function (options, callbacks) {
  if (options.loadReason === 'startup') {
    tabs.open('https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload');
  }
};
```

The documentation for this is located here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

Answer (score 1):

@canuckistani is actually right: if you're not seeing it, it's probably because your `options.loadReason` is something else. If you've got the plugin installed already, for example, you would get loadReason `upgrade` instead when you try to install the plugin again. See that url @canuckistani gave for more info.